# laptop display problem

Tags: lcd, visual-artifacts

My sony vaio laptop screen  displays pictures that are bloomed.The text as i am typing is mixture of green and blue.My  NVIDIA GEForce is disabled as the laptop wont boot with it.External monitor seems working OK.The bios password screen has a pattern of thin vertical lines and the the screen fills momentarily
with column of two ZEROES separated by a column of two zeroes etc after password is entered and before windows vista loads.Is the display or NVIDIA or both faulty.In an earlier simmilar situation the problem resolved while runnin Anti virus scan. Any clue please.Thanks
AM

Answer (score 0):

The graphic artifacts that you dealing with, are probably because of heating problems.

If it happens right after you turn on your laptop (when his cold), and the problem still occur - I assume that your video card is damaged.

If you got warranty - I suggest to use it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the cable is either lose or the monitor is going on you. If you can find a manual online to take it apart you can try to check that the cable is tight and if it is you will need to buy a new LCD screen.